# delphi custom component - catching (ctrl or alt key) keydown and keyup keyevents

Tags: delphi, components, key-events

i have a custom component (descendant from tpanel) and what i wanna do is to catch when the ctrl or alt key is down and up

any idea how can it be done?

Comment: All of the code you've posted is irrelevant. Please [edit] your post to only include **relevant** portions of your code. Don't expect us to wade through all of that clutter to see the parts that are actually related to your post.

Comment: i did the changes :) hope it looks better now?

Answer (score 1):

On way would be to override the **KeyDown()** and **KeyUp()** protected methods.  The `Key` parameter to these methods is the [Virtual Key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) that corresponds to the key that has gone down/up.

For the *Ctrl* key the key code of interest is **VK_CONTROL**.

For the *Alt* key the key code is the slightly less obvious **VK_MENU**.

These key codes do not distinguish between left/right keys on a keyboard.  If this is important you can use **VK_LCONTROL**, **VK_RCONTROL**, **VK_LMENU** and **VK_RMENU**.

So, for example, if you were to maintain the `Ctrl` key state in a boolean member variable you could set this TRUE when either `Ctrl` key does down with something similar to this:

```
procedure TMyButton.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  fCtrlKeyDown := (Key = VK_CONTROL);
end;
```

However, these events will *only* occur for keys pressed *while your control has the input focus*.

So, if a user presses the **Ctrl** key while some other control has the focus, your control will not be aware of it.  If you need to know the state of the keys at some arbitrary moment in time you call `GetAsyncKeyState()`.

To obtain the state of a key *at the time of some input event* (i.e. window message, such as a mouse button click) then call `GetKeyState()` in the code that responds to that event.

To understand the difference between the two consider that you had some `Click` handler that responded to a mouse click which triggered some processing that potentially consumed a non-trivial amount of time in which the user might press (or release) a key, followed by some further processing that depended on the key state:

```
procedure TMyButton.Click;
begin
  // .. some non-trivial processing - if the user presses or releases 
  //  the Ctrl key while this processing occurs, then this could affect
  //  how the following code behaves, depending on which 'KeyState'
  //  function is used to determine that key state ....

  // ...

  GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL);  // Will return the state of the Ctrl key at
                            //  the time of the mouse event that resulted 
                            //  in this Click code being executed, regardless
                            //  of the state of that key NOW.

  GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);  // Will return the state of the Ctrl key NOW
                                 //  regardless of the state of the key at    
                                 //  the time of the 'Click' mouse event.
end;
```

Note that the return value of [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) is not a simple boolean.  It contains information about whether the key was pressed since the last call to the function as well as the *current* state of the key.

Similarly [GetKeyState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) includes information about the "toggled" state of a key, and is also not a simple boolean.

Refer to the documentation for these API's for details on interpreting their return values.

### Responding to Input in Other Controls

If your control needs to be able to respond immediately to a key going down while some other control has the input focus, e.g. to provide some visual feedback to the user of the keyboard state, then you will need to implement some additional mechanism by which the control can be made aware of these events.

One way would be to use **KeyPreview** on the form and provide a method on the control which is required to be called whenever the form receives a key event (which with KeyPreview enabled will occur for every key event, before the actual input control receives that event.  Hence the name... the event allows the form to "Preview" the "Key" events).  This method could enable your control to determine the keyboard state and respond and react appropriately.

This however means that your control is reliant on external code (on the form) to function and still only works for keyboard events that occur while some control on the same form has the input focus.

To make your control entirely self contained, it could install a [keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) to establish an application wide "preview" mechanism.  If you have potentially lots of instances of your control in an application, you may wish to devise a mechanism which tracks those instances and uses only a single hook to update them all, rather than each control installing it's own individual hook.

I don't think it would be appropriate to go into the details of such a mechanism here.  If you have difficult implementing that then this should be addressed as a separate question (which may already be answered elsewhere on StackOverflow).

Comment: i tried overriding keydown() and keyup() methods but the problem is my component descendant from TPanel and there is no focusing on the component when component is not focused the keydown() and keydup() methosds doesnt respond and component is not catching keyevents on the form

Comment: I've updated the answer to address that I think, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: thank you deltics,
the question is how can i make my component be aware of changes of GetKeyState/GetAsyncKeyState?

Comment: i need to know if ctrl or alt key is pressed and released even my component doesnt have the focus

Comment: thank you again deltics,
i think the 'keyboard hook' aproach would be the answer for my problem
is there any example for me to understand 'keyboard hook' process?